# Smart Device Framework Signature Panel - Draw signature in full WinForms app

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile, signature, smart-device-framework

I'm planning on using the Smart Device Framework 2.3 to use the signature control panel in a Windows Mobile 5 application using the compact framework 3.5.

The control has the option to save the signature as either a byte array of points, or as a bitmap. Now seeing as I want to store the signature in a sql compact database, I guess the byte array is going to be better. The trouble is, I'm not sure how to render that in a full WinForms application after I've transferred it back to the desktop.

I need to show the signature on a report, so it would need to be an image I could link/embed into the report.

Anyone have any experience or thoughts with this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the signature capture control, storing the image as a bitmap and saving the image to the filesystem.

So for your report you can just display de image. Just keep in mind that you need to write some extra code to upload the image.

If you have an array of bytes from the signature capture you can create a representation of the image with this code

```
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
    }
```

Comment: @R Quijano, thanks for the snippet for the image from memory stream. I'd forgotten about that. I had thought about storing the bitmap in the file system and copying it down from there, and that is one option, but keeping it in the database would be easier. I'll give this a spin and let you know how it pans out.